# Set a size for a DataGridView button

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a datagridview with *DataGridViewButtonColumn type*, and I need to increase the button's *height*.
Or  increasce the rows's height.

How may I do that?

Comment: Isn't the default height of the button the height of the row?

Comment: So, how to increasce the row's height ?

Comment: `dataGridView1.Rows[0].Height = 32;`

Comment: @LarsTech Thank you man, may I use this thread to ask you another thing about DataGridView problem? All the content of the second row is always smaller (font-size, buttons, links...). I may add a print screen if you want.

Answer (score 0):

you can use *DataGridViewCellStyle* Property,

Write some code for dataGridView1.Rows[i].Height of row(s).